# Using variable intrepretation in strings and math

Tags: sass

Here is my pen:[codepen.io/JFrankParnell/pen/bNGQrQ](http://codepen.io/JFrankParnell/pen/bNGQrQ)
I'm trying to work with variables, only

```
 #{$containwidth}px;
```

is working.  Using `#{$containwidth}%;` trying to use percentages or math either will give compile errors or isnt working.

I have given the #control styles to show what I expected each of the test scss to produce.

Answer (score 0):

you can use percentage.

`width: percentage($othervar / $containwidth);`

full pen :
http://codepen.io/bravocado/pen/XJWyYK

here is the doc :
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#percentage-instance_method

hope it helps. :)